# Using a POST request to obtain a authorization token and then using POST response in a GET request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, post, get

Requested a spotify access code by using the POST method. Assigned a variable to the response. Then, tried to access the token with a GET method directly following.

```
   {
        angular.module('app')
            .controller('GameController', function($http){
                const $ctrl = this;

                $http.post('/access-token').then(function(response){
                    $ctrl.tokenResponse = response.data;
                    $ctrl.myToken = $ctrl.tokenResponse.access_token;
                    console.log(response);

                });

                   $http({
                    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks?ids=6rqhFgbbKwnb9MLmUQDhG6',
                    method: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${$ctrl.myToken}`
                    }
                }).then(function(response){
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $ctrl.tracks = response.data;
                    console.log($ctrl.tracks);
                })

        });
    };
```

It looks like the GET method is not recognizing the variables in my POST method. My ${$ctrl.myToken} is coming up undefined. "data":{"Authorization":"Bearer undefined"}. But, when I console.log the POST results BEFORE my GET method, it logs the access code just fine.

Not sure how to get my GET method to read the response from my POST method.

All of this code is in my controller.

[image]

Comment: Can't make the second request until first has completed

Comment: Put the 2nd request inside the first one's `.then` function. Otherwise the 2nd request runs before the 1st has finished (keyword: asynchronous)

Comment: I tried to move the get request inside the .then, but I'm still getting "Bearer undefined."

Comment: @charlietfl - Can you elaborate please? I'm not exactly sure how to position my GET method to make sure the POST is already completed before it runs.

Comment: Is it defined when you log first response?

Comment: When i console log the response from the POST, I get the data, but my access token doesn't show up when I GET.{data: {…}, status: 200, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", …}config: {method: "POST", transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), paramSerializer: ƒ, jsonpCallbackParam: "callback", …}data: {access_token: "BQC5rqFI9lBaPobLRWaHvcNTSH1n7pRvk-0LXMPKqu3QbExSYbUfmHcUzgQLcgL77FG6wxdbK1-K0Odrf8Y", token_type: "Bearer", expires_in: 3600, scope: ""}headers: ƒ (d)status: 200statusText: "OK"xhrStatus: "complete"__proto__: Object

Comment: @DaleBurrell All of this code is in my controller.

Comment: As others have commented above, you just need to put your get request inside the `then` function of your post request.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Tried it this way like you all suggested. It's getting my access token now, but no data. Looks like I have a totally new problem now, but at least the 1st one is solved. Thanks, everyone! :)

```
{
angular.module('app')
    .controller('GameController', function($http){
        const $ctrl = this;

        $http.post('/access-token').then(function(response){
            $ctrl.tokenResponse = response.data;
            $ctrl.myToken = $ctrl.tokenResponse.access_token;

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks?ids=6rqhFgbbKwnb9MLmUQDhG6',
                data: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${$ctrl.myToken}`
                }
            }).then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);
                $ctrl.tracks = response.data;
                console.log($ctrl.tracks);
            })

        });



});
```

};